# Pygame display image in while true loop memory problems

Tags: python, memory-management, pygame

I have a picture that changes constantly. I would like to present these in `pygame`, like a video. The memory is full and will not be released. Where is the mistake?

```
def showLive(file):
   picture = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(file),(width,high))
   main_surface.blit(picture, (0, 0))
   pygame.display.flip()

while True:
   #takePicture take always a new picture
   takePicture("test.jpeg") 
   showLive("test.jpeg")
```

Thanks a lot.

Update: 04.01.2018

I use https://github.com/alexdu/piggyphoto. To take a preview from my dslr.

When I start the program, then I see the "live view". The memory is getting fuller. After about 8 minutes it is full on the Raspberry Pi 3b.

```
import piggyphoto, pygame

def showLive(file):
   C.capture_preview(file)
   picture = pygame.transform.scale(pygame.image.load(file),(width,high))
   display.blit(picture, (0, 0))
   pygame.display.flip()

width = 1275
high = 850
file = 'preview.jpg'

C = piggyphoto.camera()
C.leave_locked()
C.capture_preview(file)

global display
pygame.init()
picture = pygame.image.load(file)
display = pygame.display.set_mode((width,high),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

while True:
   showLive(file)
```

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: One thing you should add is some kind of event handling. Either call `pygame.event.pump()` in the event loop or use an event loop similar to the one in the [`quit_pressed` function here](https://github.com/alexdu/piggyphoto/blob/master/preview.py).

Comment: I already have it. I just left it out here.

Comment: do you have the same problem when you use `C.capture_preview(file)` but you don't load image `pygame.image.load(file)` ? Maybe problem is in `piggyphoto`. You can also try `del picture` before you load new image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the solution.

https://github.com/alexdu/piggyphoto/issues/2

```
s=self.cam.capture_preview()
s.save('/tmp/preview.jpg')
s.clean()
```